# How do I upgrade the IONIC1 project to the IONIC3 project?

Tags: javascript

I have an IONIC1 project but I need to use ionic3 to extend the original functionality of this project.

1.I have tried using TS to call JS in the same ionic3 project, but I am not sure the same method can make ionic3 TS using ionic1 JS?

2.I don't know what are these codes mean? And how to turn these codes into ionic3 can be used

```
(function() {
    angular.module('starter')
    .factory('AccMeter', [ '$rootScope', '$interval', '$timeout', 'BTCommLE', 'EmmParser', accMeterService ]);

    function accMeterService($rootScope, $interval, $timeout, bt, accParser) {...}
```

Please tell me how to Solve these two problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to migrate your code to the new Angular version.
And if you migrate, I advise going straight to the Ionic version 4.

Maybe these articles can help you.

[Angular upgrade guide](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade)

[Migrating from Ionic 1.0 to Ionic 4.0 - Overview](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration#migrating-from-ionic-1-0-to-ionic-4-0-overview)

Answer (score 1):

Ionic v1 was based on AngularJs which was the first version of Angular. Whereas Ionic v3 is based on the latest version of Angular. Further, you can look into this article -

> iOS and Android support is only indirectly done by Ionic itself, but
>   more by Cordova. You can package old Ionic v1 apps in current Cordova
>   versions (cordova-android and cordova-ios), as this is controlled by
>   the Ionic CLI whose current versions still support Ionic v1 just fine.
>   I don’t expect this to change.

[ionic framework v1 to v3](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-v1-to-ionic-v3-upgrade-necessary/112474)

Answer (score 1):

All above answers are correct. There is no magic button to make ionic 3/4 project from Ionic 1.

AngularJS and Angular 2+ are very different. The same applies for CSS styles comparing to old Ionic.

From my personal experience: I had to almost completely rewrite my app.

Follow the upgrade guide, start with a new blank Ionic 3 (or better Ionic 4) project. Be ready to spent at least a week on learning principles of new Angular.